# Docusign in iOS app with 3rd party signer

Tags: docusignapi

I want to add docusign functionality to an iOS app using this API:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview

Consider this use case:

An agent visits a client in their home.  The agent brings his own iPad with my app installed.  While interviewing the client the agent fills in all the information on the iPad app that I provide.  This is a regular application; not a fillable .pdf.  A fillable .pdf is not sophisticated enough to gather all the information we need to gather.

At this point the app could generate a .pdf with all the data that was gathered.

What are my options to have the client sign the document?

Is is possible for the agent to hand the iPad to the client for signing?

Can the client sign without an email address?

What are the caveats to those options?

The docusign site is good, but it is not easy to understand the user experience from the API.

I would guess that the client needs an email address and needs to sign the forms on their device that receives email, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Docusign embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) for your usecase.

> **Embedded Signing - or the Recipient View** workflow - allows users to
>   sign directly through your app or website. When you embed your
>   recipients you are telling the DocuSign platform your app will
>   generate signing URLs, authenticate your recipients, present the
>   signing request, and re-direct once the transaction is complete.
>
> For browser integrations re-directing or framing can be used to host
>   the signing workflow, for mobile apps (iOS and Android) you should use
>   a webview.

Comment: That is a good link, but it is not clear if it is appropriate for the agent to hand his iPad to the client for signing.  The reason I bring that up is: it just does not seem secure.  It happens to be what I want to do for the convenience of the client, but if it is not secure then I can't do it.

Comment: In-person signing is a common way to obtain signatures through Docusign. https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-in-person-signing

Comment: Here is another interesting link for offline signing: https://support.docusign.com/articles/Offline-access-with-the-DocuSign-Mobile-App-for-iOS-iPad-iPhone-iPod-Touch